# Process snapshot for running DirectX programs

Tags: process, operating-system, directx, virtualization, snapshot

Is it possible to take a complete restorable snapshot of a running or suspended DirectX program while NOT within a virtualization program, like VirtualBox?  If so, how?  While the program is running natively, the snapshot would have to include enough of the OS and hardware state to restore the program without messing up the stability of the OS when it is restored a few minutes or more later.

I would like to do this on XP with DirectX 5 to 9, but ideas or solutions for Windows 7 using DirectX 5 to 11 or Linux using Wine are welcome.  I am not sure how good support is for DirectX 8 or less on the most recent Windows OSs.

For those who want to comment on the virtualization approach, I can not get solid DirectX 7 or before hardware rasterization emulation, and I do not know how to trick a pre-coded program into using reference or software rasterizers.  In other words, I would like to get 3DMark2001 and like working in VirtualBox.  I know snapshots are easier using virtualization software, but that could only work for me with DirectX 8 or later.

Comments on the stability of snapshots, using virtualization software or native OS, are welcome too.

Comment: This sounds like an X/Y problem. What are you really trying to accomplish? Debug a running executable?

Comment: To NicholasM:  Debug is a possibility, but my main intent is to save a game at a point where there is no in-game option to save.  I need to be able to restore the program to running state, including all information from any related processes, current frame, any hardware states (CPU, GPU, etc.) needed, etc. so I could continue exactly from where I saved without any corruption to the program or the OS.